# Identify and delete all unrequired fields from Shapefile using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, shapefile, arcgis-10.4

I have some Shapefiles inside one Folder and for the sake of data compression I want to delete all fields from Table of Content that can be removed (that are not required)!

What I have:

[image]

What I expect:

[image]

My code that is not working:

```
import arcpy
import os

arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Temp\"
fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

for fc in fcList:
    fields = arcpy.ListFields(fc)
    for field in fields:
        delFlds = [field for field in fields if field != "FID" or field != "Shape"]
        arcpy.DeleteField_management(fc, delFlds)
```

I am using Python 2.7 and ArcMap 10.4.1

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are listing [field objects](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-classes/field.htm) with ListFields, not the field names which should be input to DeleteField. So change:

```
[field for field in fields if field != "FID" or field != "Shape"]
```

to:

```
[field.name for field in fields if field.name not in ("FID","Shape")]
```

But it is probably better to use the `required` property since object id and shape fields can have different names in different feature classes:

```
for fc in fcList:
    fields_to_delete = [field.name for field in arcpy.ListFields(fc) if not field.required]
    fields_to_delete.pop() #Keep one non-required field
    for field in fields_to_delete:
        arcpy.DeleteField_management(fc, field)
```

Comment: Hi, Do you know why one non-required field is needed? It looks like it won't work if one non-required field is not kept.

Comment: Hi, no I dont know why

Answer (score 2):

I usually make an explicit list of fields I want to keep, then loop through and delete any others. I don't remember where I saw this method originally, but it could have come from this [discussion about keeping only certain fields](https://community.esri.com/thread/64092).

I do like @BERA's use of `field.required` and would suggest using that - though I've historically listed `OBJECTID`, `FID`, `SHAPE`, etc. explicitly.

So for example, if you needed to keep only a field called `DIMENSION` and a field called `RESPONSIBLE_PARTY`:

```
keep_fields = ["DIMENSION","RESPONSIBLE_PARTY"]

fieldNameList = []
fieldObjList = arcpy.ListFields(table)

for field in fieldObjList:
    if (not field.name in keep_fields) and (not field.required):
        fieldNameList.append(field.name)

arcpy.DeleteField_management(table,fieldNameList)
```

Comment: yes but as @BERA said field names may change from a shape file to anothet one capital letters or something like that but good to know thanks for your countribution